# Calculating negentropy in Python

Tags: python, scipy, entropy

Does anyone knows how to calculate [negentropy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negentropy) in Python? `scipy.stats` has both continuous (differential) and discrete (Shannon's) entropy. However, I could not see anything implemented for negentropy, and I bet Python already has it.

Comment: Use wiki. `Claude Shannon's` & `Loren_Graham's` equations are pretty simple to code.

Comment: Nevertheless using an implementation already there has advantages, so this question is a valid one.

Comment: @Alfe I'm just pointing a way to dig :) `Boltzmann's` thermodynamics entropy theory is also supposed to be pretty close to it

Comment: You probably don't know russian, but you can easily find equations in the text. http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B3%D1%8D%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%8F